# different #app css between dev and production with vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I have built an app with `vuetify` and `vue cli`, there is nothing wrong when I am in dev. But after I run `npm run build`, there seems to be a new default `#app` CSS generated and overwrite my CSS in the final bundled file. In my case, all the text alignment and margin on my website went crazy. The dev mode works fine but it appears only in the prod.

[CSS in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRknV.png)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from './store'
export default {
  store,
  name: 'App',
  metaInfo: {
    title: '',
    titleTemplate: 
  },
  created: function () {
  }
}
</script>

<style >
#app {
  text-align: unset;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I did not use `scoped` style in one of the deprecated components and it affects the whole app. What's strange is it didn't show up in development